# Mongoose unique validation when using subdocuments

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am creating an application that uses products and items. The admin creates a product and the users can create an item using that product.
I have created a seperate product schema so that the name of each product is unique.

```
const productSchema= new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    unique: true
  },
});
```

Then, I have also created an item schema where I have used the productSchema as a subdocument

```
const itemSchema= new mongoose.Schema({
  submitter: {
    type: productSchema,
  },
});
```

The problem is, I want the product name in the product model to be unique. But, there can be multiple items using the same product.

But, if I try to add items with same product, mongoose gives me a duplicate key error.

Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

an easy workaround is to try and fetch the product by the product name before creating the product:

```js
const product = await Product.findOne({
  name: req.name
});
if (product) {
  res.status(400).json({
    success: false,
    message: "Product Name Is Not Unique"
  });
  return;
}
```

So you can declare the product schema as:

```js
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String
  },
});
```